# How to pass data to join table on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I have the following structure:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :device_ownerships
  has_many :devices, :through => :device_ownerships
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :device_ownership
  has_one :user, :through => :device_ownership
end


class DeviceOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :device
end
```

However DeviceOwnership also has serial_number row

I want to pass serial_number value to DeviceOwnership on create. I understand I can do something like

```
def create
  user = User.create
  device = Device.create
  device_ownership = DeviceOwnership.create(:serial_numer => params[:device_serial_number], :device_id => device.id, :user_id => user.id)
end
```

This does not seem too elegant, I wonder if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :device_ownerships
  has_many :devices, :through => :device_ownerships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :devices
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :device_ownership
  has_one :user, :through => :device_ownership
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :device_ownership

  def device_ownership_attributes=(attributes)
    dev = build_device_ownership(attributes)
    dev.user = self.user
  end
end


class DeviceOwnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
  belongs_to :device
end
```

Now you can save all associations at once with in a transaction if your params are like this:

```
pramas = {"user"=>{ "email"=>"user@example.com", "devices_attributes" =>{"0"=>{"name" => "Devise 1", "device_ownership_attributes"=>{"device_serial_number"=>"xyz"}}}}
user = User.create(params['user'])
# will save User, devise, and devise ownership all at once.
```

Comment: cool, thank you.. I did not realize if I create DeviceOwnership by passing it on create with only one value, Rails will automatically assign the device.id to it.

Comment: The beauty is, everything will run with-in a MySQL transaction. Which means if some validation fails, then nothing will be saved and all COMMITS will be reverted.