# How to use the create method for a many:many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

`User` and `Organization` have a many-to-many association through `Relationship`.

The `Relationship` model, amongst other things, specifies whether the `User` is a member of the `Organization` (`member` boolean).

If a new `Organization` together with a new `User` related to that `Organization` needs to be created I currently do the following:

```
Organization.create!(name: "name", ...).users.create(email: "email@email.com",...)
```

However, this does not yet set the `member` boolean in the `Relationship` model to `true`.

Is there a way to include this in the above command? Or is this only possible separately from creating the `user` and `organization` record? Because then it would require relatively a lot of code and seems a bit inefficient to add after the previous `create` line:

```
@user = User.find_by(username: username)
@organization = Organization.find_by(name: name)
@relationship = @organization.relationships.find(@user)
@relationship.update_attributes(member: true)
```

Comment: But why do you need this boolean? If the `user` has a `relationship` with the `organization`, he is a member already, isn't he?

Comment: No not necessarily, in my use case the user could for example only be a moderator to the organization and not a member.

Comment: So in that case you'll need to set that boolean manually or have a default value for that.

Comment: With "set manually" you mean the way I do it now? I wonder whether the `Organization.create!` line is correct, though, also given the problem I've posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31750918).

Comment: I'd do it separately, first create the `organization` and then I'd instantiate a `new` user and add it to the `organization` like this: `organization.users << User.new(email: "asd@asd.com", member: true)`

Comment: I agree that would work, but shouldn't what I do also work? (if you would have all separate command/lines for creating an organization, for creating a user, 4 lines to add the attributes, all ot that seems extremely inefficient to me as each line needs to access the db,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split your create line, you can avoid some `find` methods:

```
org = Organization.create!(name: "name", ...)
user = org.users.create(email: "email@email.com", ...)
Relationship.find_by(organization_id: org, user_id: user).update_attributes(member: true)
```

I tried to see if there was an easy way to get this to work using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, but it was looking like that approach would be more complicated in this case.

This link describes setting up something similar, but it is with a `many-to-one` relationship: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941676/3993528

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I agree this makes it shorter. The `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is indeed exactly what I'm looking for and I initially had this working for a `many-to-one` relationship. Now that I've converted it to a `many-to-many` relationship it no longer seems to work (or at least it requires adjustment in the `create` methods). I have a separate post about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31750918.