# How to create a new record for a many-to-many through association that accepts nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, seeding

`Organization` and `User` have a many-to-many association through `Relationship`. Initially I implemented this a 1-to-many association, which worked but now I need it to become a many-to-many through association. So I created the `Relationship` model and changed the association in the model files.

`Organization` accepts nested attributes for `User` as in my app I have a joined signup form for the two. Also, I use it in my seeds file:

```
Organization.create!(name: "name", ...).users.create(email: "email@email.com", ...)
```

This worked when it was a 1-to-many association but now it is a many-to-many through association, it produces upon seeding the error:

```
Validation failed: Member can't be blank, Moderator can't be blank
```

This refers to variables for the `Relationship` model, through which `User` and `Organization` are associated.

What causes this error; why are these values blank? Is the `Organization.create` line perhaps incorrect for a many-to-many association? `member` and `moderator` have default values (see migration file). I would expect it to create the `organization`, `user`, and `relationship` with default values. How else should I be creating a new organization and user?

---

The Organization model:

```
has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :relationships

accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationships, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
validates_associated :users
```

The Relationship model:

```
belongs_to :organization
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

validates_presence_of :organization
validates_presence_of :user
validates :member, presence: true
validates :moderator, presence: true
```

The User model:

```
has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy 
has_many :organizations, through: :relationships, inverse_of: :users
```

The relationship migration:

```
class CreateRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relationships do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :organization, index: true

      t.boolean :member, null: false,  default: false
      t.boolean :moderator, null: false,  default: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :relationships, [:user_id, :organization_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Does your `schema.rb` show an index being created? Perhaps you missed the DB migration to create an index

Comment: The cause proofed to be `index: true` in the `Relationship` model. But now a validation error gets generated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem maybe that you haven't specified a "foreign key" for the has_many relationships in User Model. Try:

```
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "organization_id", dependent: :destroy
```

This uniquely identifies an organization per relationship with your user model.

Comment: I tried adding `foreign_key: "organization_id"` to the user model and `foreign_key: "user_id"` to the organization model, but the error upon seeding remained the same. But then I found that the cause was `index: true` in the `Relationship` model. However, now a validation error gets generated (see update in original post).